# Security issues with PHP with cPanel and shared hosting

Tags: php, security, server, cpanel

If this is not the correct forum for this question please tell me!

When one has an account on a shared server host running cPanel, the account runs in a jailed environment where access to files is restricted to /home/myaccount/ and its subdirectories.  However PHP runs as root, so is there any security issue possible where another (malicious) user could craft php scripts in such a manner as to access files in another users file area. I have heard conflicting stories about this and would like a definitive answer from a "server guru".

Comment: this is **not** the correct forum for your topic

Comment: @donald123 any suggestions as to where to ask it, server fault flagged a not totally disimilar question involving cpanel and php as off topic (not mine)

Comment: Running PHP as a root user is not a good idea. It should run as specific user. Also you will have secure your server against symlink issue and other function to prevent access to other account. If you are using CloudLinux OS, you can secure, your server easily. For sharef hosting, CloudLinux is recommended.